# Alternative function for _kbhit in C++?

Tags: c++, kbhit

I am currently trying to develop a simple snake game on ios. The tutorial requires me to use  however this does not work on my mac. What would be an alternative for _kbhit ? I am new to c++ so would appreciate any help!

Answer (score 2):

There is none. You'll have to use a library (like [PDCurses](https://pdcurses.org/) or similar) to abstract that from your code or make the platform dependent implementation yourself.

Comment: @Curly22 The library was just an example to make it simple to circumvent the fact that there is no alternative for `_kbhit` in standard C++. That said, `iOS` might have something platform specific that you could use. It wouldn't be portable, but if you only target `iOS` (or similar platforms), it may be ok.  Checkout their pages for [termios.h](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/System/Conceptual/ManPages_iPhoneOS/man3/tcgetattr.3.html) - but as I said, going with a library makes it easier and more portable.

Comment: Does iOS even ***have*** a console?

Comment: @Curly22 What would be a correct answer to your question?